# Identify the white section of a binary image

Tags: python, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to track the white section of the binary image. When the white section is detected (which is cuboid in my case) it should get the height and width and the value of left and top most pixel.

Then after getting the coordinates i want to assign them to ROI. so that i can then subscribe to /roi topic and perform a particular action.

Thanx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157096/identify-the-white-section-of-a-binary-image/) by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Detect contours.
Cycle through contours and build rectangle, which contour fit.

Use some CV lib for this task, for example OpenCV (highly recommeded). You will need do something like that:

```
// contours of targets
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;

// get contours from binary image
cv::findContours(binImg,contours,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

// poly contours
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());

// bounded rectangles
std::vector<cv::Rect> boundRect(contours.size());

for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++) {
    // get polyDPcontour and bound rectangle of it
        cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
        boundRect[i] = cv::boundingRect(cv::Mat(contours_poly[i]));
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) with karma: 123 on 2014-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on 2014-04-28**:
Thanks a lot for your time and patience.
but can you please tell me in python (without numpy) because i dont know C++...
I will really appreciate it..!

**Comment by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) on 2014-04-29**:
Sorry, i'm not good in python. But OpenCV has python wrappers of every c++ function with the same names. So it will be easy for you to translate from c++ to python. Also you should take a look in python contour sample here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/contours.py